# Unable to call method due to parameters

Tags: c#, winforms

I am not sure which parameters i am meant to pass when calling the function in this If/Else statement.

The If/Else statement is calling 1 of 2 functions, Online_Version or Offline Version.

Code is as follows:

```
  public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Would you like to run the Event Register?", "Registration Selection", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            label5.Text = "Event Registration";
            textBox1.Select();
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            var fileSave = new FileStream(fullFileName, FileMode.Create);
            fileSave.Close();
            OfflineRegister();

        }
        else
        {
            label5.Text = "ICAS Register";
            textBox1.Select();
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            var fileSave = new FileStream(fullFileName, FileMode.Create);
            fileSave.Close();
            OnlineRegister();

        }
    }

    public void Online_Register(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        OnlineRegister();
    }

    public void Offline_Register(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        OfflineRegister();
    }

    public void OnlineRegister()
    {
        SqlConnection DBConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DATABASE;Initial Catalog=imis;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        Object returnValue;

        string txtend = textBox1.Text;
        string lastTwoChars = txtend.Substring(txtend.Length - 1);

        if (textBox1.Text.Length != 6 && e.KeyChar != '*') return;

        //cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT last_name +', '+ first_name +'\t ('+major_key+')\t' from name where id =@Name");
        cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT last_name +', '+ first_name from name where id =@Name");
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name", textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", "")));
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = DBConnection;

        //Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
        //TimeIn = "Time In: ";
        //TimeOut = "Time Out: ";
        returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar() + "\t (" + textBox1.Text.Replace(@"L", "") + ")";
        DBConnection.Close();

        if (listBox1.Items.Contains(returnValue))
        {
            for (int n = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
            {
                string removelistitem = returnValue.ToString();
                if (listBox1.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(n);
                    //listBox1.Items.Add(removelistitem + "    " + 'TimeOut' + 'Time');
                }
            }
        }
        else

            listBox1.Items.Add(returnValue);

        textBox1.Clear();

        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fullFileName);
        foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
            sw.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();

        if (listBox1.Items.Count != 0) { DisableCloseButton(); }
        else
        {
            EnableCloseButton();
        }
        label6.Text = "Currently " + listBox1.Items.Count.ToString() + " in attendance.";
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    public void OfflineRegister()
{
  Object returnValue;

        string txtend = textBox1.Text;
        returnValue = textBox1.Text.Replace(@"*", "");

        if (e.KeyChar != '*') return;
        {
            if (listBox1.Items.Contains(returnValue))
            {
                for (int n = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
                {
                    string removelistitem = returnValue.ToString();
                    if (listBox1.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
                    {
                        //listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(n);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(returnValue);
                textBox1.Clear();
                System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fullFileName);
                foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
                sw.WriteLine(item.ToString());
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
                if (listBox1.Items.Count != 0) { DisableCloseButton(); }
                else
                {
                    EnableCloseButton();
                }
                label6.Text = "Currently " + listBox1.Items.Count.ToString() + " in attendance.";
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: They look like they should be used as event handlers to me. Probably to handle Key Press events. Something like `this.KeyDown += OfflineRegister;` is probably what you are looking for. Then, when a key is pressed, your `OfflineRegister` handler will respond to the firing of the event.

Comment: Without any more detail about what the methods do, the only reasonable guess would be the parameters to the Form1_Load function, sender and e.

Comment: I think you should wrap up the code in the event handlers in some methods and call those methods in your `if/else`

Comment: Try to pass Form1_Load function's parameters in _Register(...) methods.

Comment: Practically all your code is duplicated within these two conditions. You should extract the common functionality outside and just handle the part where these two cases differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do is take the code ouf of the `Online_Register`/`Offline_Register` event handlers and put it in a different methods called: `OnlineRegister` and `OfflineRegister` for example, that way you can do this:

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Would you like to run the Event Register?","Registration Selection", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            label5.Text = "Event Registration";
            textBox1.Select();
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            var fileSave = new FileStream(fullFileName, FileMode.Create);
            fileSave.Close();
            OfflineRegister();

        }
        else
        {
            label5.Text = "ICAS Register";
            textBox1.Select();
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            var fileSave = new FileStream(fullFileName, FileMode.Create);
            fileSave.Close();
            OnlineRegister();

        }
    }

    public void Online_Register(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
       OnlineRegister();
    }

    public void Offline_Register(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
       OfflineRegister();
    }

    public void OnlineRegister()
    {
     // Do Stuff
    }

    public void OfflineRegister()
    {
     // Do Stuff
    }
```

This is of course assuming that you actually need the `KeyPress` event handlers.

**Explanation**

The bottom of the code above shows two methods which I just created. These can be called from within your event handlers and on the `Form1_Load` event. This is useful as you won't have to repeatedly paste the same code over and over again.

**Improvements**
You could improve your current scenario by taking the `Register` code and putting it inside a different class, maybe called, `RegisterHelper` or something, which serves the purpose of providing logic for Registering users.

Furthermore, you could give your Form a name that's a little more appropriate, instead of `Form1`.

Comment: When I re-list the code like this i can't use my `if(e.KeyChar != '*') return;` because i can't pass the `e`. This is located in my Register Online and Offline

Comment: In that case, you can send across the `e` parameter to the Online and Offline methods. Just add a parameter in the methods `char character` or something. If the form load you can just send null. In the Online and Offline methods you can check if it's null or not.

Comment: Sorry I dont really understand the parameters of C# too much yet. I have editted my post to show my current code state

Answer (score -1):

Check the FullFileName variable value, methods looks perfect.  Always segregate the UI and functional events.